# [Literature Request]: Counter factual estimation and modelling

Tags: probability, reference-request, book-recommendation, mathematical-modeling, bayesian

I'm hoping that someone may be able to help me. I'm beginning a project in which requires asking "what would have happened if X didn't happen", specifically whilst using Bayesian analysis and methods. I'm wondering if anyone knows any good literature on counterfactual modelling/estimation etc

I'm more than happy to sieve through papers, textbooks etc so please feel free to throw it all at me.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Judea Pearl's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judea_Pearl) book [Causality. Models, reasoning, and inference](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/), in particular chapters 7 and 8. Be aware that Pearl's framework is only one of several competing approaches and is seen as controversial by some. The answers and comments to the question, [Criticism of Pearl's theory of causality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26437/criticism-of-pearls-theory-of-causality), from [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) contain and link to a lot of information that may also be useful to you.

*Pearl, Judea*, Causality. Models, reasoning, and inference, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-89560-6/hbk). xviii, 464 p. (2009). [ZBL1188.68291](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1188.68291).,

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'll look into them